# How to replace a pattern permanently in a file using pipe Unix command

Tags: shell-script, yaml

I have following lines, so I just want to replace particularly

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
```

to

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
```

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    # If enabled and optional is set to true, encrypted and unencrypted connections over native transport are handled.
    optional: false
    keystore: XXXXXX
    keystore_password: XXXXX

    # Set require_client_auth to true to require two-way host certificate validation
    require_client_auth: true
    #
    # Set truststore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
```

Comment: Please edit your question with readable formatting -- it looks like most of it should be a [code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714), but I'm not sure. Also, please clarify what you're trying to do: is this in a file that needs to be changed in-place, or something else? What does a pipe have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is a YAML file, we may use a command-line YAML parser, like `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
yq -y '.client_encryption_options.enabled |= false' file.yml
```

This updates the value of the `enabled` key in the `client_encryption_options` top-level object to `false`.

To make the change in-place, use `yq` with its `--in-place` or `-i` option.

This `yq` is a wrapper around the `jq` JSON wrapper, and will therefore strip comments from the document.

---

If you are using the `yq` program from https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/, which is the one you get if you install `yq` using `snap` on e.g. Ubuntu, then use

```bsh
yq eval '.client_encryption_options.enabled |= false' file.yml
```

... and use its `--inplace` or `-i` option for doing in-place edits.

This `yq` will not strip comments from the file.